# How to make the <img> tags line up horizontally in the div?

Tags: html, css, image

I need to make the images show up side by side horizontally in the div. How can I do that?

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/TFT.png" alt="Smiley face" height="90" width="95" />
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Ltyt.png" alt="Smiley face" height="90" width="95" />
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/artspng" alt="Smiley face" height="90" width="95" />
</div>
```

Reference: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bWhhj/)

Comment: show us the HTML of how you are aligning this IMG in the first place.

Comment: Start by giving us more information... HTML, maybe a jsfiddle.net to give us an idea of what you've already tried

Comment: Update the html portion in your code, so that other can answer better.

Comment: @justcode, You have a jsFiddle typo. The last `img` tag of your jsFiddle is improperly closed. However, your posted markup in the message comments has this tag closed correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also use css properties **display:inline-block** or **float : left** to achieve this.

HTML Code

```
<div>
    <img ... />
    <img ... />
    <img ... />
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
div img{ display: inline-block;}
```

or

```
div img{ display: block;float: left;margin-right: 5px;}
```

Comment: Using the markup you gave, only the first two pictures align horizontslly...pls do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try increasing the width of the container they are in. Probably they don't fit so they break to another line.

Answer (score 4):

On the general assumption of your code being something like this

```
<div>
    <img ... />
    <img ... />
    <img ... />
</div>
```

Then, a simple CSS property will get the job done.

```
div img { display: inline; }
```

---

On seeing your HTML portion. You can use the following CSS to get them online.

```
.partners img { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `inline`, which robs you of a lot of the control that comes with `block` elements, or changing their vertical align, I'd float them:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div.img_holder img
            {
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "img_holder">
            <img src="" />
            <img src="" />
            <img src="" />
            <img src="" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Floating is a peculiar science of its own in CSS; it's very much worth learning as it can yield some very powerful results.  For example, were these `divs`, and not images, using `inline` would keep you from setting their height.  `Inline` also affects how `margins` and `padding` work.  `vertical-align` is inconsistent between browsers and, if I'm not mistaken, shouldn't actually yield the results you're looking for, at all.

Comment: I used the float property and only 2 pictures aligned horizontally....do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Floats will behave a little bit like inline elements in that they will wrap if their parent isn't big enough.  Setting the parents width (in my example, `img_holder`) to the appropriate should help.  If not, could you provide a screen shot?  Your images are each 95 pixels wide (according to the above) do they also have margins or padding?

Answer (score 0):

now you can used to

Your **default link** is http://tinkerbin.com/ob9HFOA4

**Css**

```
   img{
   display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
```

live demo http://tinkerbin.com/a5BxIZrs

Answer (score 0):

Firts of all, in order not to mess up your other images you're probably going to add, do this:

```
.Wrapper img{ float: left; }
```

This will float all your images within the .Wrapper class to the left. If all images in the page where these css rules are called will be aligned to the left, do this:

```
.Wrapper img{ float: left; }
```

**EDIT:** Add this rule to .Wrapper

```
.Wrapper{ width: 100%; }
```